# viewforoverlay never gets called

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkoverlay, mkmapviewdelegate

This is driving me nuts.  I've been through all the posts on stackoveflow, but nothing fits the bill.  I am trying to add a simple polyline (i.e. not a custom overlay) as an overlay to my `MKMapView`.  The `viewForOverlay` method on the delegate never gets called.  The map delegate is correctly called for every other delegate function.  Here is the code from the `viewForOverlay` method:

```
//maanges the overlay
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay{

    NSLog(@"does it ask for the overlay view?");

    MKOverlayView *overlayView = nil;

    return overlayView;
}
```

Here is the code where I construct the polyline and add it to the map:

```
    MKPolyline *thePolyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pts count:[arrOfPoints count]];

    [thePolyline setTitle:@"line"];

    [mapView addOverlay:thePolyline];
```

The polyline does in fact have my collection of points (about 1000), so I don't think the issue is there.  Am I missing some required property or some other implementation on the map view?

**EDIT** Shows the code for polyline `MKMapPoint` generation:

I use an xml file with about 1100 points to generate the polyline as part of an appConfig process.  I read and parse the file with `NSXMLParser` and `NSXMLParserDelegate` respectively.  Here is the code that generates the points (from the `foundCharacters` method in the `NSXMLParserDelegate` protocol):

```
//NSXMLParserDelegate methods...
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

    if(POINT){
        NSArray *arr = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

        MKMapPoint pt = MKMapPointMake([[arr objectAtIndex:1]doubleValue], [[arr objectAtIndex:0]doubleValue]);

        MapPointObject *thePoint = [[MapPointObject alloc] init];
        thePoint.mapPoint = pt;

        //gives the mkmappoint to the array of points.
        [arrOfPoints addObject:thePoint];

        [thePoint release];
    }
}
```

and here is the where the points actually generate the `MKPolyline` and gives it to the mapView
 (from the `didEndElement` method on the `NSXMLParserDelegate` protocol):

```
   if([elementName isEqualToString:@"appConfig"]){
        MKMapPoint *pts = malloc([arrOfPoints count] * sizeof(MKMapPoint));

        for(int i = 0; i <= [arrOfPoints count] - 1; i++){
            MapPointObject *pointObject = [arrOfPoints objectAtIndex:i];
            pts[i] = pointObject.mapPoint;
        }

        MKPolyline *thePolyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pts count:[arrOfPoints count]];
        [thePolyline setTitle:@"line"];

        //adding the polyline to the model's mapview
        Model *theModel = [Model sharedModel];

        [theModel.mapView setVisibleMapRect:thePolyline.boundingMapRect animated:YES];
        [theModel.mapView addOverlay:thePolyline];

        free(pts);
    }
```

The point count property on the `MKPolyline` does in fact say that there are 1100 points in it.

**EDIT:** sample XML values:

```
<appConfig>
<point>-94.847587,38.977967</point>
<point>-94.844111,38.977978</point>
<point>-94.844108,38.977369</point>
<point>-94.844003,38.977369</point>
<point>-94.843955,38.974886</point>
```

Comment: Can you show how `pts` gets populated?  Since you're using polylineWithPoints, make sure `pts` is filled with MKMapPoint values instead of CLLocationCoordinate2D values (or use polylineWithCoordinates instead).  Make sure `arrOfPoints count` is exactly how big `pts` is.

Comment: @AnnaKarenina - I think I am doing it correctly, no?  I just posted my code, maybe take a quick peak at it?  Thanks!

Comment: Does the xml file store coordinates (lat, long) or MKMapPoint values (they're not the same thing)?

Comment: It's just a point xml element with coordinates pairs that looks like this: <point>-94.847587,38.977967</point>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xml file contains coordinates (latitude and longitude) values.  These coordinate values are not the same thing as `MKMapPoint` values (which are the map view's x,y projection of the lat/long onto the flat map).

You should be storing coordinates and not `MKMapPoint` values (which you are).

So instead of using `MKMapPoint` and `polylineWithPoints`, use `CLLocationCoordinate2D` and `polylineWithCoordinates`.

In the xml parser method, create and store a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` using `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake`.

The `pts` array should be of type `CLLocationCoordinate2D *` and when doing the `malloc`, use `sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D)`.

Then call `polylineWithCoordinates` instead of `polylineWithPoints`.

By the way, you'll also need to actually return a non-nil overlay view in `viewForOverlay` after making the above changes otherwise you still won't see the line:

```
MKPolylineView *polylineView = [[[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay] autorelease];
polylineView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
polylineView.lineWidth = 2.0;
return polylineView;
```

Comment: Sorry about the lengthy pause, I got pulled off on some other stuff.  Thanks for the info, I hadn't realized the difference between MKMapPoint and CLLocationCoordinate2D.  Changing it still didn't resolve my issue, though.

Comment: While you're debugging this, can you put just 2 points in the XML file instead of 1100?  Next, right before calling polylineWithCoordinates, NSLog the CLLocationCoordinare2D values in pts[0] and pts[1] (eg `NSLog(@"pts[0]=%f,%f", pts[0].latitude, pts[0].longitude);` and similarly for pts[1]).  What values does it show?

Comment: Did you add the creation of the MKPolylineView to viewForOverlay and does that method get called?  Also, what is `Model`?  It seems strange that you have a map view in a singleton?  What is it a subview of?

Comment: Does the map's visible rect change to where you expect?  If you replace the call to setVisibleMapRect with `theModel.mapView.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance (CLLocationCoordinate2DMake (38.977967,-94.847587), 1000, 1000);` does the map at least zoom to that location?  You also mentioned other map delegate methods are working.  Which are they and are they in the same file as viewForOverlay?

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I really appreciate it.  I got the issue resolved, I just needed to change the order of the parameters in CLLocationCoordinate2DMake.  Thanks again, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Great.  Actually I realized later that there was a simpler fix instead of switching all your code to use CLLocationCoordinate2D and that is just change the line where you do MKMapPointMake to MKMapPointForCoordinate(lat,long).  So take the coordinates from the xml file and convert them to MKMapPoints.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I got the issue resolved, but given that @AnnaKarenina's original solution solved the problem, I marked it as the answer.  I am just posting this to make additional info available for anybody else that comes upon it.

When I originally wrote the code, MKMapPointMake takes parameters like this: `MKMapPointMake(x,y)`.  When I switched it, `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake` takes parameters like this: `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat,lng)`, or in cartesian terms, `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(y,x)`.  For my particular set of coordinate pairs, this doesn't exist and so it never called the viewForOverlay delegate method.  I changed the order of parameters for the CLLocationCoordinate2DMake constructor and everything works fine now.

Comment: I have same problem, I tried your solution, but still have same problem

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.mapView addOverlay:polyline];
[self.mapView setNeedsDisplay];
```

force refresh mapView by calling setNeedsDisplay :)